# Pandas interpolate changed in version 0.10?

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

Just installed pandas 0.10.0 and the following line to create an interpolated version of an existing columns fails:

```
prep_bcgps['lati'] = prep_bcgps['lat'].apply(pds.Series.interpolate)

TypeError: unbound method interpolate() must be called with Series instance as first argument (got float64 instance instead)
```

Can somebody direct me to the new syntax?

Thanks,

Luc

Comment: Your old code used to work "by accident". Calling the column's `interpolate` method as below is the correct way.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
prep_bcgps['lati'] = prep_bcgps['lat'].interpolate()
```

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X' : [1, None, 3, None, 5]})
print(df)
#     X
# 0   1
# 1 NaN
# 2   3
# 3 NaN
# 4   5

df['X'] = df['X'].interpolate()
print(df)
#    X
# 0  1
# 1  2
# 2  3
# 3  4
# 4  5
```

Comment: Just a heads up. When there is trailing NaNs in your DataFrame, the behavior of `interpolate()` may not be the way as you expected. See [example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25255496/dataframe-interpolate-extrapolates-over-trailing-missing-data) and [example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54792206/pandas-dataframe-interpolate-with-method-linear-and-nearest-returns-incons).