# Pandas.DataFrame interpolate() with method='linear' and 'nearest' returns inconsistent results for trailing NaN

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I was exploring `pandas.DataFrame.interpolate()` with different methods, `linear` vs. `nearest`, and I found different outputs from the two methods when there is missing data at the trailing.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd # version: '0.16.2' or '0.20.3'
>>> a = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [np.nan, 1, np.nan, 3, np.nan, 5, np.nan]})
Out[1]: 
   col1
0   NaN
1   1.0
2   NaN
3   3.0
4   NaN
5   5.0
6   NaN

>>> a.interpolate(method='linear')
Out[2]: 
   col1
0   NaN
1   1.0
2   2.0
3   3.0
4   4.0
5   5.0
6   5.0

>>> a.interpolate(method='nearest')
Out[3]: 
   col1
0   NaN
1   1.0
2   1.0
3   3.0
4   3.0
5   5.0
6   NaN
```

It seems that `linear` method will do extrapolation of the trailing NaN while "nearest" method will not, unless you specify `fill_value = 'extrapolate'`:

```
>>> a.interpolate(method='nearest', fill_value='extrapolate')
Out[4]: 
   col1
0   NaN
1   1.0
2   1.0
3   3.0
4   3.0
5   5.0
6   5.0
```

So my question is why the two methods behave differently on handling trailing NaN? Is it what it is supposed to be or it is a bug?

The same results were found with two versions of pandas, '0.16.2' and '0.20.3'.

`pandas.Series.interpolate()` also shows the same issue.

There is a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25255496/dataframe-interpolate-extrapolates-over-trailing-missing-data)  and a [github issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8000#issue-40056131) talking about a similar problem but with a different purpose. I am looking for an explanation or a conclusion for this issue.

EDIT:

Correction: the way `linear` method behaves is not exactly `extrapolation`, as you can see the filled value of the last row is 5 instead of 6. It looks more like a bug now, is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `df.interpolate(method='linear')` forward-fills NaNs after the last valid value. That is rather surprising given that the method name only mentions "interpolate".

To restrict `df.interpolate` to only interpolate NaNs between valid (non-NaN) values,
as of Pandas version 0.23.0 [(Reference)](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/35812eaaecebeeee0ddf07dee4b583c4eea0778), use [`limit_area='inside'`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [np.nan, 1, np.nan, 3, np.nan, 5, np.nan]})
a['linear'] = a.interpolate(method='linear')['col1']
a['linear inside'] = a.interpolate(method='linear', limit_area='inside')['col1']
print(a)
```

yields

```
   col1  linear  linear inside
0   NaN     NaN            NaN
1   1.0     1.0            1.0
2   NaN     2.0            2.0
3   3.0     3.0            3.0
4   NaN     4.0            4.0
5   5.0     5.0            5.0
6   NaN     5.0            NaN
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification. @jreback also pointed to the same direction. But I just tried with pandas 0.22.0 but still didn't see the expected results. Any ideas? Thanks! `a['linear inside'].values: [ nan,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   5.]`

Comment: If the code above is producing that result on pandas 0.22.0 then that is a bug. But if you were to file a bug report the first thing the developers will ask you to do is upgrade to the latest version. FWIW, `limit_area` appears to work as expected on pandas 0.24.0.

Comment: Yes, pandas 0.24.0 gives the expected results as in your example. Thanks again for the help! It seems like the `limit_area` in pandas 0.22.0 does not behave as it should be.

Comment: Confirmed. `limit_area` works as expected in pandas 0.23.0+, but not in 0.21.0 or 0.22.0. The [github commit](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/commit/35812eaaecebeeee0ddf07dee4b583c4eea0778) also indicates 0.23.0+. So maybe the pandas [document](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html?highlight=interpolate#pandas.DataFrame.interpolate) needs to be updated?

Answer (score 4):

@D.Weis it is great question let me explain in deep and there is no thread and github issue. Let me explain step by step.

```
>>> a = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [np.nan, 1, np.nan, 3, np.nan, 5, np.nan]})
Out[1]: 
   col1
0   NaN
1   1.0
2   NaN
3   3.0
4   NaN
5   5.0
6   NaN
```

1.)Interpolation by 'linear'

In 'linear' interpolation the missing values are filled up by two nearest position value. While in 'nearest' interpolation it will fill up the missing values by nearest surrounding values, however, in 'nearest' the missing value will have the same values as nearby position value. I have explained 'nearest' interpolation more deeply in section (2).

Emaple for 'linear' interpolation:

```
    1   1.0    1. 1.0 
    2   NaN    2. 2.0
    3   3.0    3. 3.0
    4   NaN    4. 4.0
```

Here, the 2nd position is empty. So to fill it up the values it will take values of position 1st and 3rd which is 1.0 and 3.0 respectively. Remember again in 'linear' interpolation it takes just 2 surrounding values to fill it up the missing value.

```
(1.0+3.0/2) =2.0 = Answer for  2nd position. Similarly it will be for other values.
```

2.) Interpolate by 'nearest'

```
>>> a.interpolate(method='nearest')
Out[3]: 
   col1
0   NaN
1   1.0
2   1.0
3   3.0
4   3.0
5   5.0
6   NaN
```

Basically, in 'nearest' interpolation it fills up missing values by the same values from nearest values. For instance,

```
1   1.0    1. 1.0 
2   NaN    2. 1.0
3   3.0    3. 3.0
4   NaN    4. 3.0
```

So, in the above example, you can easily see that position 2nd takes the same valeus of position 1st because it is the nearest value to the 1st position. In, short just keep in mind that in 'nearest' interpolation the missing values are filled up by the same value with the help of nearest surrounding values.

In `method='nearest', fill_value='extrapolate'` you can see in your example it will fill up the last values with the same value of the 5th position. The concept remains the same as for filling up missing values as explained above.

NOTE:
Moreover, there are other interpolation methods such as 'bilinear','bicubic', etc. It is all about accuracy for filling up the missing values.

My suggestion is if you want to make a selection from 'nearest' and 'linear' interpolation. I would say go with 'linear' interpolation because it will fill up values more accurately than that of 'nearest' interpolation.

Hopefully, this will help you. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the explanation of the concepts of two interpolation methods. But the question in the OP is about why the trailing missing data is handled differently by the two interpolation methods of pandas, and additionally, why the output from "linear" interpolation seems incorrect.

Comment: @ D. Weis as there is no 2nd neighboring value in the tail so it would take the same value as above.